# Foundation 5 accordion not working on touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, accordion, zurb-foundation-5

My accordion systems are working on desktop and clicks, but aren't working on touch screens or mobile.  Not sure how to fix this or what is wrong.  [www.revivalfloatspa.com/massage](http://revivalfloatspa.com/massage) is the site.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronously loading jquery was breaking it for mobile devices.  Removing async defer from my javascript files fixed it.